# Под что подводят?

Tags: фразеология

Подвести - значит, не выполнить обещанное. А под что, собственно, подводят? Откуда пошло это выражение? От поговорки "подвести под монастырь" или от чего-то другого?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут не один вопрос, минимум - два, а то и три. 
Во-первых, о самом значении "подвести". Это не обязательно "не выполнить обещанное", значение более широкое. А поскольку значение слова в выражении "подвести под монастырь" тоже не вполне ясно, говорить о связи одно с другим не приходится.

Для начала.

> > **подвести**  
> > 8. (кого-что). Разг. 
> > Своими действиями поставить в затруднительное, неприятное положение, обмануть чьи-л. надежды, ожидания. Вы меня п. хотите? //  
> > Вызвать какие-л. затруднения у кого-л. своей неисправностью, качеством или плохим   состоянием. Электричество подвело. Здоровье подвело. Погода не подвела.

Далее. "Подвести", видимо, аналогично современному "подставить" (под опасность, неприятность). Очень выразительно, если считать что такая опасность приходит сверху.

Если принять эту версию, получается, что "подвести под монастырь" может быть частным случаем: монастыри превращались в крепости, и если вражеское войско попадало под их стены, у него могли возникнуть большие неприятности.
Это далеко не единственная версия по поводу монастыря, но поскольку вопрос так не стоит, то я их и перечислять не буду, легко найти в Интернете.

Answer (score 3):

Подвести - *подставить* (под удар).
В словаре Михельсона 1903-04 есть разъяснение :

> Подвести кого (иноск.) — подъ бѣду, подъ отвѣтъ, ввести въ бѣду.
> Подвести кого подъ капель.

Нацкорпус :

> Г. П. Данилевский. Воля (1863)
> Как бы не **попасть еще под ответ** перед князем! ...
> Отца-то моего, отца-изверга, да и эту барыню **под ответ бы подвести**.
>
> С. В. Ковалевская. Нигилистка (1884)
> В профессорском кружке, где Васильцев вращался до тех пор, меньше всего пришло бы кому-либо в голову заподоздрить его в трусости; наоборот, товарищи постоянно дрожали, как бы он своей неуместной строптивостью и их **не подвел под ответ**.

Вариант выражения существовал и в другом виде, но он стал использоваться в литературном контексте только после революции, ввиду (как считают некоторые исследователи русской фразеологии) не совсем приличного смысла :

> А. Т. Аверченко. Шутка мецената (1923)
> Не такой вы человек, **чтоб другого под монастырь подвести**.
>
> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 2 (1960). 
> Взяли бы они верх над коммунистами ― вот тогда и мне можно было бы к ним пристать на готовенькое, а так ― очень даже просто **подведут они меня, как слепого, под монастырь...**
>
> Владимир Маканин. Утрата. (1984)
>  Слепцы — люди, живущие в утрате своей, так пояснялось. В те времена слепцы брали мальчишку, обычно из сирот, брали совсем малого, кормили его и поили, за что он и водил их по белу свету. Слепцы не были из добрых; конечно же, они помыкали мальчишкой, отчего у мальчишки день ото дня за душой накапливалось, даже неосознанно. К тому же мальчишка рос: он начинал чувствовать мир, озорничал и нет-нет проявлял мстительность, единственную, уникальную в своем роде, когда после перехода, после долгого пути слепцам надо было справить нужду. «Мальчик, — просили они его, — а ну-ка, милый ты наш, найди-ка нам укромное место», — а он подводил их под окна и стены монастыря, необязательно даже женского. Место у монастыря было такое, что подвоха не почуять, воистину тихое и укромное, не улица и не базар, и совсем нетрудно вообразить сцену, как слепые рассаживаются, а затем и кощунство под окнами, и крики, и как выскакивают на них с дубьем. Мальчишка же, разумеется, поглядывал, затаившись поодаль и корчась от смеха, с тем чтобы после избиения слепых зрячими предстать перед слепыми вновь и оправдываться, что его привлекло, мол, тихое место, что это случайность и что он сам, видит бог, сидел с ними рядом.

Кто кого подвел и куда - решать благоразумному читателю...

Одно из первых употреблений глагола *подвести* ( = поставить в затруднительное положение) без управления с предлогом *под*  :

> Н. Г. Помяловский. Молотов (1861)
> Он некоторых начальников глубоко ненавидел, но **ни разу не подвел их**, хотя и имел к тому много случаев...